# Kendo UI - Source code for Demo Service

Tags: html, kendo-ui, telerik

Kendo UI Online demo use service, is the source code available for these services?

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Products

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service

I am interested in looking at service methods to find out how Odata end points are exposed.

Comment: You can view the source code using browser tools. For example, it's Ctrl + U in Firefox.

Comment: Need to see service method implementation, not html

Answer (score 0):

Source code of the services are available on Github:

[link](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-demos-service)